# How to fill variables in a bash script from another txt file, like .env in docker?

Tags: bash, variables

I've a template bash script with N variables that I need to change when someone ask for it.
To preserve the code and avoid any stupid mistake, I like to send those variables from another file. Like everyone on does with an .env file in Docker.

So if I've the following...

Template script:

```
varName= 
varLastname=
varURLProfile=
```

...can I use a .txt file like this to pass the variables from here to previous the script to keep it intact?

.txt file:

```
varName= foo
varLastname= bar
varURLTwitter= https://twitter.com/foobar
```

How?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure ! You can use `.` or `source` to do that :

`source dotEnvFile.txt myScript`
or
`. dotEnvFile.txt myScript`

Just make sure not to have a white caracter in your variable definition. Not `varName= foo` but `varName=foo`